# Changing the delay timer? (c#)

Tags: c#, task, delay, wait

Short Question.
This is my Code.

```
var t = Task.Run(async delegate
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
    return 42;
});
t.Wait();
```

Thats what I will work with in General. But later in my Code I Need the delay to vary. I tried something like this already but I that does not seem right:

```
t.Wait(page*11);
```

(Whenever I click a button the variable "page" would Change. So Pretty much a new value everytime)

Comment: If all you're using the task for is the `Delay` method, and then using a blocking `Wait` on that task you might as well scrap the whole thing and just use `Thread.Sleep()`

Comment: `await Task.Delay(page*11);`?

Comment: I think he is misunderstanding the `Wait` parameters. It is for timeout but he seems to be understanding it as the amount of time to wait for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare a variable and pass it's value to the delegate you pass in Task.Run as below:

```
// define here the delayParam
int delayParam = 10;

var t = Task.Run(() => 
{
    await Task.Delay(delayParam);
    return 42;
});
t.Wait();
```

The return type of Task.Run is a `Task<T>` or just a `Task` if nothing it's returned. You can block on waiting the result of a Task, like you already do, by calling the `Wait` method. You can't pass arguments to the result...

Comment: You may as well just do `Task.Delay(delayParam).Wait();` instead of creating and waiting for `t`. Though I don't think `Wait()` should be used at all. Either `When()` in an async method or just use `Thread.Sleep()`

Comment: @p3tch of course you can do...just wanted to answer in the OP contex, in which he has used a block...Indeed your one liner in this specific case is fine.